# Expected a value of type 'List<CartItem>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to fetch a data with database "Firebase", i create a future  function, get the url, creating response variable for geting the url , then i exctracted data but an error was raising : ' Expected a value of type 'List'.
this is a code:

```
`class OrderItems {
  final String id;
  final double amount;
  final List<CartItem> products;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  OrderItems({
    required this.id,
    required this.amount,
    required this.products,
    required this.dateTime,
  }); 
Future<void> fetchAndSetsOrders() async {
    final url =
        "https://ecomercemobileapp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/orders.json";
    try {
      final List<OrderItems> loadedorders = [];
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(extractedData);
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        extractedData.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
          // final products = orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>;
          loadedorders.add(
            OrderItems(
              id: orderId,
              amount: orderData['amount'],
              products: (orderData['products'] as List<CartItem>),
              dateTime: DateTime.parse(orderData['dateTime']),
            ),
          );
        });
        _ordre = loadedorders;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

`
```

Error ::

```
`Expected a value of type 'List<CartItem>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'`
```

thank you for help guys !!

Comment: Share your code for `CartItem`

Answer (score 0):

orderData['product'] get list with dynamic object
you cannot change it CartItem List directly

```
List<CartItem> cartItemList = await getCardItem(orderData['product']);
Future<List<CardItem>> getCardItem(List<dynamic> products){
List<CartItem> tempList = new ArrayList();
for(var data in products){
    tempList.add(CartItem.fromJson(data));
}
return tempList;
```

}

And add JsonSerialization in CartItem model.